# MVC Render Model or ViewBag into HTML template

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've a Control/View that render a HTML template Into the View with:

```
@(MvcHtmlString.Create(@Model.TemplateContent))
```

This works fine, but I would also like to make a Merge, I mean:

The Model.TemplateContent contains, for example, a model item like a:

```
Model.TemplateContent = "<p>The Name of the Customer is @Model.CustomerName</p>";
return View(model);
```

Is possible when View render Model.TemplateContent, render the model items into html template too?

Comment: you are somewhat mixing two concepts: rendering a view and outputting a string.

Comment: Yes this is true, but is that the customer need. I need a full result with a merge with Model and RawHTML, to generate a full View with all content. It's better that this will do before of Render?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC3 Razor - create view from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890046/asp-net-mvc3-razor-create-view-from-a-string) [take also a look to related questions]

Comment: check out http://razorengine.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.Raw(Model.TemplateContent)
```

@Html.Raw(string) returns markup that is not HTML encoded